# Executing storm program but cannot find a class

Tags: maven, build

I simply cloned the project from https://github.com/storm-book/examples-ch02-getting_started, but when I execute it with command

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="TopologyMain" -Dexec.args="src/main/resources/words.txt"
```

I got the following error message.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Getting-Started 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.3:java (default-cli) @ Getting-Started ---
[WARNING] Warning: killAfter is now deprecated. Do you need it ? Please comment on MEXEC-6.
[WARNING] 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TopologyMain
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:281)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.771 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-06-01T11:29:45-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/160M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3:java (default-cli) on project Getting-Started: An exception occured while executing the Java class. TopologyMain -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Hi @user2895478, I just start learning storm with the Getting Started with Storm book and have the same problem, did you solve it finally?

Answer (score 1):

You should run `mvn compile`, which will produce `TopologyMain.class`, before you can execute it with `mvn exec:java ...`.

This can be specified in single mvn command by chaining targets

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="TopologyMain" -Dexec.args="src/main/resources/words.txt"
```

Comment: Hi @divanov, I tried your method but it still don't work. I still get the " Unknown lifecycle phase ".mainClass=TopologyMain"." error.

Comment: @yan9yu: there should be no space before `.mainClass`.

Comment: Here is my new command,  `mvn -f pom.xml clean install compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="TopologyMain" -Dexec.args="src/main/resources/words.txt"`, I ran it in project folder but still get the `MojoExecutionException` exception

Comment: I updated my answer with an exact command, but I guess there is something else in your problem. Consider asking a question.

Comment: Hi @divanov, it's me again. I tried your new solution and it is magically solved my problem, even through I still don't know why. I think there may be something wrong with my maven configuration. Anyway, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try maven clean and install before running the command. From command prompt you can do the following

```
mvn -f pom.xml clean install
```